# Capturing warning message from mysqli bind_params

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

If you execute `mysqli_stmt->bind_params(...)` with an incorrect number of parameters, you get the following warning showing up in the browser:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]:
Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in ...
```

Fixing the coding problem is easy, but I'm not finding it easy to grab ahold of that warning myself in order to control how it's displayed (in the likely chance that I'll cause more warnings in the future). I'd like to:

- Suppress the warning being displayed automatically
- Grab ahold of the warning message and display it on my own terms

Simply calling `@mysqli_stmt->bind_params(...)` seems to work for suppressing the default warning message being displayed. Is this the best approach?

And the only information that I seem to get from `mysqli` is that the call to `mysqli_stmt->bind_params` returns `FALSE`. However, perhaps because this is a warning, there is no data in `mysqli->error` or `mysqli_stmt->error`. Accordingly, it is not clear to me where I can find the text for that message. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: properly written code shouldn't be causing the errors, and using `@` to suppress them is never a good idea.

Comment: As I emphasized in the question, I'm not interested in suppressing the error completely, I'm interested in capturing the message in order to be able to control how it's output. Two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have PHP 5.3+, the method you're looking for is `error_get_last` - [PHP docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php). Here's a quick example:

```
$success = @$mysqli_stmt->bind_params(...)
if ( !$success ) {
    $einfo = error_get_last();
    $an_output_str = "Error of type (".$einfo['type']."): ".$einfo['message'];
    // $einfo['file'] and $einfo['line'] are also filled with useful info
}
```

**EDIT:**

As the other gentleman suggested below, in looking towards the future, it might be wise to consider a more general solution to warnings/errors that cannot be dealt with cleanly through return values and/or easy-to-read error value settings. In this case, you might want to explore `set_error_handler`, which was supported all the way back in PHP 4.01 - [PHP Docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

The most basic implementation might look like so (mimicking what I wrote earlier):

```
function deal_with_error($errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline) {
    $an_output_str = "Error of type (".$errno."): ".$errstr;
    // $errfile, $errline also have useful info
}

set_error_handler("deal_with_error");
```

As for the different values of `$errno`, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). For instance, the warning that you were getting would have an `$errno` of 2.

Comment: this is wrong and awfully unreliable way of handling errors. You cannot write this lengthy code for **the every operator in your script,** can you?

Comment: First of all, it sounds like your issue is with the question, in that you think something else should have been asked. I'm not going to pass judgement on all that, I just answered what was asked. Secondly, most (if not all) of the PHP functions that relate to prepared statements allow the caller to deal with errors through mysqli->error (or mysqli_stmt->error) - the 'Return Values' section of [mysqli->store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) is a good example - whereas bind_params is an exception to this, so "for every operator in your script" doesn't really apply here.

Comment: mysqli operators are not only operators in the code. in reality, literally every operator can raise an error - foreach, include, explode - whatever. One cannot predict where error can occur. So, it is common handler required, yet it makes such manual handling obsolete.

Comment: Of course you're right. However, that is not what was asked. The author wanted to know how to deal with a specific error in mysqli code that doesn't behave like the other functions, so I answered her. Perhaps a better question is how to deal with any error created by PHP that can't be dealt with simply through "status/return" values, but, again, that is not what was asked. Nevertheless, it's sound advice to recommend that she look into it.

Comment: I would understand if it was a meaningful error, like from getimagesize or file_get_contents with url. But this one has absolutely no particular meaning for the application logic. Altough I respect your intent for a direct answer, SO suffers from direct (yet useless) answers a lot, so I disagree with it. Judging by your reasoning, you are not that noob by the way.

Comment: Well, I'll let the author judge which answer is more useful: Providing some information to work with - now and in the future - or cryptically telling her that she's asking the wrong question :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed info. I will definitely look into `set_error_handler` for a more general solution, but at least this gets me up and running for the moment. TBH, I'm disappointed that I didn't come across this info myself, as the PHP documentation on it looks quite solid. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: As a quick follow-up: `set_error_handler` isn't really applicable in this particular context, as I'm trying to make a self-contained `db` class (should've mentioned that), so I don't want to impose a general error-handling system on the code that's using my class (and `bind_params` is the only function that I have to deal with this way). However, I was not aware of the larger issues here, and so I greatly appreciate the info on `set_error_handler`, as I'll undoubtedly make use of that myself in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Although your intent is right, it is badly worded (which will bring some wrong answers) and - strictly speaking - irrelevant to mysqli errors but rather to all the PHP errors in general.

There is the way to do it

> Suppress the warning being displayed automatically

this one is simple.

```
display_errors = 0
```

in `php.ini` will take ALL the PHP errors off screen.

> Grab ahold of the warning message and display it on my own terms

You don't actually need to display this particular error in your own terms but rather display a generalized 500 error page. There are many ways to do that. One of simplest is to define a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) which will intercept all the errors and show whatever text you wish. Just don't forget two inportant things:

- to log the error message
- to send a 500 HTTP header

However, a way better approach would be to make HTTP server to serve such a page. It will let even parse errors handled properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm not interested in suppressing all PHP errors, and although I might not "need" to display this error in my own terms (whatever that means), I would "like" to - hence the question :) Rather than just killing the process and saying there was an error, I'd like to say **what** the error was.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. You *are* interested in "suppressing" all PHP in my terms: which are getting **them off screen** on a live server. Just like any other web-developer in the world.

Comment: Look, you have an excellent question. But some of your assumptions are wrong or incomplete. They all can be corrected though if you let me.